# For loop, why is the last condition always executed?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am confused with `COND3` in a `for` loop in C. I always thought that the last condition is not executed at the last iteration, but instead the flow is the following:

```
  START
    |
    v
+-------+
| COND1 |
+---+---+         +-------+
    |<------------+  CODE |
    |             +-------+
    |                 ^
    v                 |              
+-------+         +---+---+
| COND2 |--true-->| COND3 |
+-------+         +-------+
    |
    v
+-------+
| COND3 |
+---+---+   
    |
    v
   END
```

Where:

```
for(COND1; COND2; COND3) { CODE }
```

It seems bizarre to repeat COND3, this flow doesn't seems logical. For instance in this code the `COND3` is repeated before the end:

```
int main(void) {
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++, printf("-"))
        printf("%d", i);
}
```

Which gives:

```
0-1-2-
```

Comment: Better to see it as `for(Initialization (int i=0;); Loop condition (i<10); Code to be executed after each loop (i++)) { CODE }`

Comment: The 3 clauses are not COND1, COND2, and COND3.  They are CODE1, COND, CODE2.

Comment: After the third hyphen COND2 is checked again but fails this time. You won't see this, but the loop exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a false premise.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is no such close reason. If "OP is confused" was a valid close reason, we'd have to close down half the site.

Comment: @Lundin: There is such a close reason (false premise, not confusion); I picked it from the menu. It is a subset of the “other” category. Closing down half the site would be an improvement, if it were the less useful half.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
expr1;
while (expr2) {
    statement;
    expr3;
}
```

The last condition checked for is `expr2`, given that the loop exits normally (no return or break statements) and `statement;` does not contain a `continue` statement. See the discussion below.

Comment: About right as long as `statement;` does not contain a `continue`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `continue` progresses the loop to the next iteration without executing the remaining part of the current loop. It does not influence expr2 which decides about leaving the while clause.

Comment: In the `while`, a `continue` in `statement;` skips `expr3;`.  In the `for`, a `continue` in `statement;` does not skip `expr3;` - thus not quite  equivalent.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I agree with that, but would consider it a special case. Will annotate this to the question, thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 6):

That isn't the layout. The third expression, the increment, is unconditionally executed *after* the `CODE` bit. The actual flow is like this.

```
  START
    |
    v
+-------+
| INIT  |
+---+---+         +-------+
    |<------------+  INC  |
    |             +-------+
    |                 ^
    v                 |              
+-------+         +---+---+
| COND  |--true-->| CODE  |
+-------+         +-------+  
    |
    v
   END
```

Comment: Curiously not in this example: `int main() {
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++, printf("-"))
        printf("%d", i);
}
` I get this output: `0-1-2-`, so `INC` is repeated before `END`

Comment: @nowox I don't think you and StoryTeller are in disagreement.

Comment: @nowox Note the INC after CODE before COND is checked in the above diagram. This aligns with your code example.

Comment: @nowox: Your statement that the flow shown in this answer does not occur in the example in your comment is false. Trace the flow. After “2” is printed in CODE, “-” is printed in INC, then COND is tested, and the loop stops.

Answer (score 2):

`COND1` is executed one time at the beginning of the loop

`COND2` is executed / and evaluated on each circle -> the loop is only executed on true

`COND3` is executed at the end of each loop before the next turn

Or in other words, the updateStatement is exdecuted each time a turn is complete (it is executed before the testExpresssion is evaluated).

```
for (initializationStatement; testExpression; updateStatement)
{
    // statements inside the body of loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is evaluated after each lap of the loop. There's nothing illogical, the C standard (C17 6.8.5.3/1) simply states (emphasis mine):

> `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement`
>   ...
>   The expression ***expression-3* is
>   evaluated** as a void expression **after each execution of the loop body**.